Configure metadata in building the token extension program
I am a newbie and am practicing construction. I don't know if my friend's construction is correct or not.I hope everyone can help
I am building a token program with metadata extension, how to load token data to arweave and then integrate into token program with metadata extension.
this is test case

const metadataConfig = {
  name: "Sleep Token",
  symbol: "SLEEP",
  uri: "https://i.pinimg.com/control/564x/51/ad/cc/51adcc91320b5b15f39e73a74b9a4934.jpg",
};



  it("init token!", async () => {
    const tx = await program.methods
      .initializeToken(metadataConfig)
      .accountsPartial({
        payer: wallet.payer.publicKey,
        mintAccount: mintPDA,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([wallet.payer])
      .rpc();

    await confirmTransaction(tx, provider);
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });


To upload metadata you can use the irys gateway in collaboration with umi plus the irys plugin
const collectionImagePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "collection.png");
 
const buffer = await fs.readFile(collectionImagePath);
let file = createGenericFile(buffer, collectionImagePath, {
  contentType: "image/png",
});
const [image] = await umi.uploader.upload([file]);
console.log("image uri:", image);
 
// upload offchain json to Arweave using irys
const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson({
  name: "My Collection",
  symbol: "MC",
  description: "My Collection description",
  image,
});
console.log("Collection offchain metadata URI:", uri);

Here's a link to this on the Solana courses -> https://solana.com/developers/courses/tokens-and-nfts/nfts-with-metaplex#part-1-creating-an-nft-collection
Here's more on uploading assets using Umi from Metaplex -> https://developers.metaplex.com/umi/storage

After uploading, put the uri in the configuration in the program, right?
